# Is it possible for a constructor to accept a number of parameters defined by a previous parameter?

Tags: java, constructor

Say you have the following class:

```
public class MyClass {

    public MyClass() {
    }
}
```

I want to be able to pass a definable amount of parameters in a constructor, something like this:

```
    public MyClass(int parameters, int /* "parameters" amount of integers here*/) {
    }
```

I know I can use the ellipsis operator, but then the constructor will accept more or less parameters than the int "parameters". Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Is there a reason to avoid using a `List<int>`?

Comment: No, what you're describing is [Dependent Typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type), which isn't supported by about 99% of all programming languages (including Java).  All I can think of is to throw an exception (or something along those lines) if `parameters` doesn't match the actual number of parameters passed in.  If you really want to use dependent types, then use a language like [Cayenne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayenne_%28programming_language%29).

Comment: I think that you should use the "ellipsis", and perform the validation inside your constructor (for example, raising an exception if the number of parameters is different than the `parameters` value)

Comment: You are essentially forcing yourself to send the same information twice.  I would just pass the elipsis argument and drop the number of parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't enforce this restriction in the Java compiler, but you can enforce it an runtime, by throwing an `IllegalArgumentException`:

```
public MyClass(int numParameters, int... parameters) {
    if (numParameters != parameters.length)
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Number of parameters given doesn't match the expected amount of " + numParameters);
    // Rest of processing here.
}
```

This uses Java's [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) feature to accept an unknown number of parameters.

Note: I've renamed the parameters a bit for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

`public MyClass(int parameters, int /* "parameters" amount of integers here*/) {
}`

See [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) about *Defining Methods*:

> The parameter list in parenthesis—a comma-delimited list of input
>   parameters, preceded by their data types, enclosed by parentheses, ()

The parameters don't tell you **how much** data it expect, it tell you the **data type**.

If you want, you can check the *amount* inside the constructor at runtime:

`if(parametersAmount != desiredAmount) ...`

Answer (score 0):

I'm gussing that the first argument will be a named constant, and it differentiates different cases

```
new MyClass(CASE_ONE, p1);
```

You can use  factory methods

```
public static MyClass createCaseOne(int p1){ ... }

public static MyClass createCaseTwo(int p1, int p2){ ... }

public static MyClass createCaseThree(int p1, int p2, int p3){ ... }

...
```